# Powershell script invoke-expression looking at string parameter passed to script called and finding errors in it

Tags: powershell, invoke

I have a script that collects error messages, and it calls another script with the error string so my other script can email me about the error. However, invoke-expression seems to be looking within the string I pass, and reporting errors.  I tried cleaning unusual characters from within the string in case that was the issue, but I'm out of characters to remove that seem like they would be an issue. **So, we are debugging the call to invoke-expression, not the error message I am posting below. I already know that I commented out the step that creates the directory it is missing.**

This is my error string:

```
Could not find a part of the ph 'EDisasterBackuptoLoc_20190123PrivilegesPrivileges_HH_Bakcsv'Exception No such ph EDisasterBackuptoLoc_20190123PrivilegesPrivileges_HH_Bakcsv  Exception SystemManagementAutomionItemNotFoundException Cannot find ph 'EDisasterBa
ckuptoLoc_20190123PrivilegesPrivileges_HH_Bakcsv' because it does not exist
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs PSDriveInfo drive ContainerCmdletProvider provider CmdletProviderContext context
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString ph CmdletProviderContext context Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProviderContext context CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProviderContext context ProviderInfo provider CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString phs String copyPh Boolean recurse CopyContainers copyContainers CmdletProviderContext context
    MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException No such ph EDisasterBackuptoLoc_20190123PrivilegesPrivileges_EDC_Bakcsv  Exception SystemManagementAutomionItemNotFoundException Cannot find ph 'EDisasterBackuptoLoc_20190123PrivilegesPrivi
leges_EDC_Bakcsv' because it does not exist
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs PSDriveInfo drive ContainerCmdletProvider provider CmdletProviderContext context
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString ph CmdletProviderContext context Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProviderContext context CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProviderContext context ProviderInfo provider CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString phs String copyPh Boolean recurse CopyContainers copyContainers CmdletProviderContext context
    MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException No such ph EDisasterBackuptoLoc_20190123PrivilegesPrivileges_SMH_Bakcsv  Exception SystemManagementAutomionItemNotFoundException Cannot find ph 'EDisasterBackuptoLoc_20190123PrivilegesPrivi
leges_SMH_Bakcsv' because it does not exist
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs PSDriveInfo drive ContainerCmdletProvider provider CmdletProviderContext context
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString ph CmdletProviderContext context Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProviderContext context CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString ph Boolean allowNonexistingPhs CmdletProviderContext context ProviderInfo provider CmdletProvider providerInstance
    SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString phs String copyPh Boolean recurse CopyContainers copyContainers CmdletProviderContext context
    MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecord
```

This is a portion of my script:

```
#cleanse string and add to global string
function CleanseString($tempStr){
   $temp2Str = $tempStr -replace "\-"
   $temp3Str = $temp2Str -replace "\:"
   $temp4Str = $temp3Str -replace "\/"
   $temp5Str = $temp4Str -replace "\,"
   $temp6Str = $temp5Str -replace "\."
   $temp7Str = $temp6Str -replace "\*"
   $temp8Str = $temp7Str -replace "\\"
   $temp9Str = $temp8Str -replace "\("
   $temp10Str = $temp9Str -replace "\)"
   $temp11Str = $temp10Str -replace "\+"
   $temp12Str = $temp11Str -replace "\["
   $temp13Str = $temp12Str -replace "\]"
   $temp14Str = $temp13Str -replace "\-"
   $temp15Str = $temp14Str -replace "\&" #replace space with nothing
   $temp16Str = $temp15Str+"`r`n" #add newline to error log so it's readable
   $temp17Str = $temp16Str -replace "\@" #replace at symbol with nothing
   $temp18Str = $temp17Str -replace "AT"#, "location" #replace AT  with location 
   $temp19Str = $temp18Str -replace "at"#, "location" #replace at  with location 
   return $temp19Str
}

[string] $errorCodeAsString = ""
foreach ($item in $global:ErrorStrings){
   $errorCodeAsString += $item 
}
if($errorCodeAsString -ne "")
{
   $errorCodeAsString = CleanseString($errorCodeAsString)
   write-output  $errorCodeAsString
   #$errorCodeAsString = "Error in Privilege script. Length error $errorCodeAsString.length " + $errorCodeAsString
   $ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
   $ScriptPathFilename = Join-Path -Path $ScriptPath -Child "\EmailAlertFailure.ps1"
   Invoke-Expression "$ScriptPathFilename $errorCodeAsString"
   #Invoke-Expression "& `"$ScriptPath\EmailAlertFailure.ps1`" $errorCodeAsString" 
   Exit 99
}
Exit 0
```

This is the error message I get when I step over the invoke-expression line:

```
SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString ph Boo ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...MshGlobPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhStrin ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...alifiedPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadP ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...omMonadPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:5 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMon ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...omMonadPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:6 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString phs Stri ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...lCopyItemString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException : The term 'MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:7 char:5
+     MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MicrosoftPowerS...RecordException:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:8 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString ph Boo ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...MshGlobPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:9 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhStrin ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...alifiedPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:10 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadP ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...omMonadPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:11 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMon ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...omMonadPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:12 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString phs Stri ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...lCopyItemString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException : The term 'MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:13 char:5
+     MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecordException  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MicrosoftPowerS...RecordException:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:14 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberExpandMshGlobPhString ph Boo ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...MshGlobPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:15 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberResolveDriveQualifiedPhStrin ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...alifiedPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:16 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedMonadPhsFromMonadP ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...omMonadPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMonadPhString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:17 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionLocionGlobberGetGlobbedProviderPhsFromMon ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...omMonadPhString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString : The term 'SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:18 char:5
+     SystemManagementAutomionSessionSteInternalCopyItemString phs Stri ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SystemManagemen...lCopyItemString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecord : The term 'MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecord' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:19 char:5
+     MicrosoftPowerShellCommandsCopyItemCommandProcessRecord
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MicrosoftPowerS...ndProcessRecord:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Before I removed at or AT from the string parameter, the error message was telling me that AT is a deprecated command or something. The problem is that invoke-expression is looking into the string I'm passing and trying to execute the parameter, $errorCodeAsString. I tried the line for invoke-expression with the &, but the error message complains about & for that version.

I've been looking into the [call command](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) , but I'm not sure if I can use that instead of invoke-expression with a parameter.  I'd also be open to suggestions of a better way to email my error message to myself.

***update:**
I tried using

```
Invoke-Expression "&'$ScriptPathFilename $errorCodeAsString' "
```

with single quote, and get this error message:

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\me\Documents\2018\powershellFiles\EmailAlertFailure.ps1 Could not find a part of the ph ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ &'C:\Users\me\Documents\2018\powershellFiles\EmailAlertFailure. ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\me...part of the ph :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of question [47074872](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074872/)? (See my answer there, not the incorrect accepted answer.)

Comment: The error message is different, plus I think it's looking into my parameter string and not passing it.  I tried the & in the commented out invoke command, and the error message complained about &.

Comment: Is it single quote or backticks around the scriptPath? Does that need to go around the parameter too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following, using call operator:

```
& $ScriptPathFilename $errorCodeAsString
```